# Java, Jersey, Hibernate - How to pass entity which is defined as OneToMany mapping via a rest call?

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, dropwizard

I have two entities - Company and CompanyOffice. Company has a OneToMany mapping with CompanyOffice and CompanyOffice has a ManyToOne mapping with Company.
While creating a new company office, I should be able to give a company id in the request.
I am using Dropwizard framework with Hibernate ORM.

Company.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Company {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
private long id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "company_name")
@JsonProperty("company_name")
private String companyName;

@JsonIgnore
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(targetEntity=CompanyOffice.class, mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<CompanyOffice> companyOffices;

@JsonCreator
public Company(@JsonProperty("company_name") String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}
}
```

CompanyOffice.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "CompanyOffice")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CompanyOffice {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
private long id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "office_name")
@JsonProperty("office_name")
private String officeName;

@Column(name = "created_at")
@CreationTimestamp
private Date createdAt;

@Column(name = "updated_at")
@UpdateTimestamp
private Date updatedAt;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
private Company company;

@Transient
@JsonProperty("company_id")
private long companyId;

public CompanyOffice(String officeName, Company company) {
    this.companyId = company.getId();
    this.company = company;
    this.officeName = officeName;
}
```

}

CompanyOfficeResource.java

```
@POST
@Timed
@Path("add")
@UnitOfWork
public Long addCompanyOffice(CompanyOffice companyOffice) {
    Company parentCompany = companyOffice.getCompany();
    String officeName = companyOffice.getOfficeName();
    CompanyOffice newCompanyOffice = companyOfficeDAO.createCompanyOffice(
            new CompanyOffice(officeName, parentCompany)
    );
    return newCompanyOffice.getId();
}
```

JSON request sent via rest call : 
{
  "company_id": 1,
  "office_name": "PW"
}

Company with ID 1 exists in the DB. How should I proceed for this? What's the right way to do this?

To simplify further,
What's the best way to pass an entity of Object A in a request to create a new entity of Object B? Object A has OneToMany relation with Object B and Object B has ManyToOne relation with Object A.

Comment: Please explain what the downvote was for.

Comment: I still haven't figured this out. Anyone? Let me know if you need more information around this.